# Redeploying Custom code workflow solution after workflow manager reinstallation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, workflow-manager

I have reinstalled workflow manager 1.0 on a SharePoint 2013 server after Workflow and Service Bus certificate expiry. Some of the 2013 workflows are referencing to custom code.

I found the deployment package.

It contains 3 files:

wsp file
dll file
and an xml file

I have copied the dll to workflow manager bin and activity folder and redeployed the wsp file.

I cannot figure out what to do with the xml file.

the XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AllowedTypes>
  <Assembly Name="ServiceDesk.WCA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=qwertyuio">
    <Namespace Name="ServiceDesk.WCA">
      <Type>AddUserActivity</Type>
      <Type>CreateNewADUserActivity</Type>
      <Type>GetOrganizationManagerActivity</Type>
      <Type>GetTermCustomPropActivity</Type>
      <Type>UpdateUserInfoActivity</Type>
      <Type>TerminateUserActivity</Type>
      <Type>CheckUserStatusActivity</Type>
      <Type>CreateNewFolderActivity</Type>
      <Type>EnableMailboxActivity</Type>
      <Type>EnableMailboxCloudActivity</Type>
      <Type>CloseMailboxActivity</Type>
      <Type>AssignOffice365LicenseActivity</Type>
      <Type>RetractOffice365LicenseActivity</Type>
      <Type>EnableLyncAccountActivity</Type>
      <Type>DisableLyncAccountActivity</Type>
    </Namespace>
  </Assembly>
  <Assembly Name="SP.2013.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=12345678">
    <Namespace Name="SP._2013.Common.Utilities.Helpers">
      <Type>ADConnectionHelper</Type>
      <Type>IOConnectionHelper</Type>
    </Namespace>
    <Namespace Name="SP._2013.Common.Utilities">
      <Type>PropertyBagHandler</Type>
      <Type>SecureStoreHandler</Type>
    </Namespace>
  </Assembly>
  <Assembly Name="ServiceDesk.Interface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567890">
    <Namespace Name="ServiceDesk.Interface">
      <Type>ADGroupManager</Type>
      <Type>IOManager</Type>
    </Namespace>
    <Namespace Name="ServiceDesk.Interface.Azure">
      <Type>AzureManager</Type>
    </Namespace>
    <Namespace Name="ServiceDesk.Interface.Lync">
      <Type>LyncManager</Type>
    </Namespace>
    <Namespace Name="ServiceDesk.Interface.OM">
      <Type>ADUser</Type>
    </Namespace>
    <Namespace Name="ServiceDesk.WCA.Utilities">
      <Type>SecureCredentials</Type>
    </Namespace>
  </Assembly>
</AllowedTypes>
```

Comment: The XML is just a description of your dll file.